# How to Parse Web Page Text For Specific Word Using Jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, url, jsoup

I'm trying to build a method that takes in a URL and reads through all the text on the webpage for a specific word to return. So far my test method looks like this:

```
public static String urlSuccessUnknown(String url) {
    Document doc;
    String res = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        res = doc.body().text();
        System.out.println(res);
        if(res.indexOf("Dimmu Borgir") > 0)
            return "METAL";
        else
            return "not metal :(";
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return "Unable to correctly parse";
}
```

But no matter what I test, the return is always "not metal :(", even when I pass a URL for a Wikipedia page that should return "METAL". I'm testing the URLs:

```
https://www.bestbuy.com/
https://www.tamu.edu/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimmu_Borgir
```

The last link for sure should return "METAL", but it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: Does `System.out.println(res)` visibly print text with "Dimmu Borgir" (in that exact case) ?  You also need to test indexOf against `>= 0` not `> 0`

Comment: Yes, the println visibly prints "Dimmu Borgir" as actually the first two words, so I thought it should work. Sorry for the lame test case. But I think that fixed it, such a stupid little mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From Alex K.,

indexOf >= 0 instead of > 0.

Also, I tested contains() and it didn't seem to work then.